# Inserting each value from int array into database - Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sqlexception

What i have is a multi-select Jlist box which the users selects several features. I grab the ID of these and store them into an int[] array.

What i am trying to do with these is insert them into my database base as below. But this is causing a

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

exception to appear. The line in question is the point at which the statement is executed. Ive checked the array isn't null and produces the correct values. I am unsure what would be causing this error.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        try {
            String strQuery = "INSERT INTO home_feature(home_id, feature_id) VALUES (?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);//prepare the SQL Query
            stmt.setString(1, homeID);//insert homeid
            stmt.setInt(2, features[i]);//insert featureid.
            stmt.executeQuery();//execute query

            dataAdded = true;//data successfully inserted

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dataAdded = false;//there was a problem, data not inserted
        }//end try
    }
```

Am I inserting the list of values correctly? Or should I be approaching this from a different angle?

Comment: Are you sure home_id field is varchar in the database?  It it was number it could explain the error.

Comment: Can you share the values of `homeID` and `features` array ?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should prepare the statement only once. Preparing the statement multiple times defeats the purpose of cursor reusability.

Answer (score 0):

One flaw I see is:

```
stmt.executeQuery();    // execute query
```

should be

```
stmt.executeUpdate();   // execute query
```

When executing DML (Data Manipulation queries) you should use 
[**PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing a non valid number in query. Check the values of `homeID` and `features[i]`.

ORA-01722 Cause:

> The attempted conversion of a character string to a number failed
>   because the character string was not a valid numeric literal. Only
>   numeric fields or character fields containing numeric data may be used
>   in arithmetic functions or expressions. Only numeric fields may be
>   added to or subtracted from dates.

Action:

> Check the character strings in the function or expression. Check that
>   they contain only numbers, a sign, a decimal point, and the character
>   "E" or "e" and retry the operation.